# Cocoa resize NSImage while preserving animation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nsimage, animated-gif

is there a way to resize a `NSImage` (animated gif) and preserve the animation?
I want to make the animated gif with 512x256px size, fit a rect of 256x256px.

```
[newImage lockFocus];

[animatedGif drawInRect:newRect
        fromRect:NSMakeRect(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height)
        operation:NSCompositeCopy
        fraction:1.0f];

[newImage unlockFocus];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing animated gif NSBinaryImageReps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917836/editing-animated-gif-nsbinaryimagereps)

Answer (score 0):

I would save the first picture of the animated gif. When you are going to resize the NSImage, just draw the first image of the animation.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: this is what is happening atm, but i need the all animation, not just the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can animate it manually with a timer which shows every 0.1 second another frame?